# Wordpress sidebar below content

Tags: html, css

I have read the articles already, citing that when the sidebar goes under the content it means that usually there's a missing or an extra `div` causing the sidebar to wrap out, or that the content or sidebar's width is too wide till it moves out of place. I've checked mine and I still can't find where I have gone wrong.

Full screen fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nwZB4/embedded/result/).
**JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nwZB4/**

Comment: create just a skeleton and remove unnecessary code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question as I have finally figured it out.

There was an extra line in the header.php which forces the entire content to scale down.

```
<div id="content">
```

Answer (score 0):

try this if

```
#sidebar {
      float: right;
      margin-right: 10px;/*1%*/
      padding-right: 0;
      width: 290px;/*29%*/
}

#content {
      margin: 0 auto;
      width: 1000px;/*100%*/
}
#main {
      clear: both;
      float: left;
      padding: 40px 0;
      width: 700px;/*70%*/
}
```

Comment: It does make the sidebar go next to the content, but isn't what I'm looking for here and this brings side effects.

Comment: I am proud to have fix the problem myself. It's nothing to do with that, it's about the extra `<div id=content">` in the header.php.